# Type-checking vs. Duck-typing in an "overloaded" Python constructor

Tags: python, variadic-functions, typechecking, duck-typing

I want to have a Python class whose instances can be built in a variety of ways.

I read some answers in SO about duck-typing in python, but since my arguments will be some combination of sequences and strings, I am not sure at all I am doing things the pythonic way.

I want to handle:

- A single, "splittable" string;
- A single sequence of numbers or strings (one argument);
- A variable length argument list composed by strings or numbers;

Most doubts remain about:

- The need to differentiate or not between a single string and a single sequence (since string can sort of behave as a sequence);
- The use or not of `try` vs `if`.
- The use of `try` vs raising exceptions "by hand".

Here is my current code, which work for some initial use cases so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import re

class HorizontalPosition(object):
    """
    Represents a geographic position defined by Latitude and Longitude

    Arguments can be:
        - string with two numeric values separated by ';' or ',' followed by blank space;
        - a sequence of strings or numbers with the two first values being 'lat' and 'lon';
    """

    def __init__(self, *args):

        if len(args) == 2:
            self.latitude, self.longitude = map(float, args)

        elif len(args) == 1:
            arg = args[0]

            if isinstance(arg, basestring):
                self.latitude, self.longitude = map(float, re.split('[,;]?\s*', arg.strip()))

            elif len(arg) == 2:
                self.latitude, self.longitude = map(float, arg)

        else:
            raise ValueError("HorizontalPosition constructor should receive exactly one (tuple / string) or two arguments (float / string)")


    def __str__(self):
        return "<HorizontalPosition (%.2f, %.2f)>" % (self.latitude, self.longitude)


    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.latitude
        yield self.longitude


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print HorizontalPosition(-30,-51)       # two float arguments
    print HorizontalPosition((-30,-51))     # one two-sized tuple of floats
    print HorizontalPosition('-30.0,-51')   # comma-separated string
    print HorizontalPosition('-30.0 -51')   # space-separated string

    for coord in HorizontalPosition(-30, -51):
        print coord
```

Comment: It seems odd to call this `HorizontalPosition`. That makes it sound like it only has 1 dimension.

Comment: I wouldn't give this multiple construction options at all. The string constructor sounds like you're tying the constructor too closely to your program's input format, and the sequence constructor can just be `HorizontalPosition(*coords)`, which unpacks `coords` and calls the 2-argument constructor.

Comment: @user2357112 (regarding your last comment) then the question would be: "so how can I achieve this?". As far as I know, I cannot have ACTUAL overloads in Python... Handling between `HorizontalPosition((lat, lon))` and `HorizontalPosition(lat, lon)` should be performed inside a single constructor, bit I don't know HOW should I do it and why.